# .SD subsetting and accessing column in the parent's data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I would like find 10 years returns in a data.table:

```
DT <- data.table( year = 2000:2020, price = 0:20 )
```

For sequencial years above (2000, 2001, 2002, ...) I can just lag the price series by 10 and divide (remembering to add the NAs):

```
DT[ , list( year, return = c( rep(NA,10), price[ 11:.N ]/price[ 1:(.N-10) ] - 1 ) ) ]
```

The problem arises if the years are not sequencial, i.e. 2002 is missing. Lagging will missalign the years, so I'd like to explicitly match year variable by subsetting the data.table like this.

```
DT[ , list( year, return = .SD[ year == ( year* + 10 ) ]$price/price - 1 ) ]
```

In the example, **year** is suppose to refer to the column in .SD, while **year*** is referring to the year column in DT. The code above doesn't work obviously since **year*** is not valid. Replacing **year*** get("year") doesn't work. I would like to replace year* with something that would accomplish this.

**Edit:** So eddi comment suggests I that I can create the parent's version of year using:

```
DT[ , { year.parent = year; list( year, .SD[ year == (year.parent + 10) ]... ) } ]
```

The answer is correct, but my code example wouldn't work as I intended. Back to using merge!

Thanks!

Comment: How can we answer the question: what if it is not [sequential]? That's something you need to specify. And you need to say in natural language or by specifying the right answer what steps are being proposed.

Comment: No probs, I have edited the question to include an example that works, though really I'm asking about accessing .SD's parent's variable in .SD.

Comment: You could do `DT[, {year.parent = year; list(..., .SD[year == (year.parent ...)}]`, which would answer your question's title, but your code doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: I fail to understand how 'year in DT' is different from 'year in .SD'. Describe _in English_ what is supposed to be returned in the secod or third rows.

Comment: Thanks eddi, I didn't know about {}. Learning more about data.table everyday!

Comment: BondedDust, .SD is subsetted from DT, so it has the same column names. What happens when I refer to year: there are two versions, one in the subset (.SD), the other in the parent (DT). So I'd like to access the parent's year column, which is unfortunately named the same thing! eddi's comment adds a column year.parent, a different name so it is possible to access it inside .SD
Not sure why it's not working, since this works fine:
DT[ , { year.parent = year; list( year, return = .SD[ year == year.parent ]$price/price - 1 ) } ]

Comment: I see, .SD subsets the whole of DT in one go... for some reason I thought it creates a seperate subset per parent's row (duh). eddi, if you'd like please post an answer

Comment: Explaining the process is a fundamental part of programming. If you don't make an effort to communicate with something other than failing code, then you are doomed to code in isolation. I suggest you join the community of people who share a common natural language. Luke, _use natural language_.

Comment: Have you seen `roll=TRUE`? Have you understood keys?  If you key by (id,date) you can lag in `i` and likely `roll=TRUE`. See also `rollends=` to control before the beginning and after the end of each time series.

Comment: @tanvach feel free to post that edit as an answer yourself

Comment: Hey Matt, yes I sometimes use roll but I don't want to match the closest year, it's the price 10 years previous. For multi-statement solution I just merge a copy of DT with year subtracted by 10.